# how to detect activity button click in fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

Only thing that i want is to detect button click in fragments .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to interact between fragments and activities, and you can find them by searching here on SO, but the easiest way I've found so far and the one I love using the most is a 3rd party library, called [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

You can simply post an event on button click, custom event which can carry all kinds of data, and then in your fragment, simply write a method that listens for that event and does whatever is necessary.

Comment: are you sure that this lib support this kind of interaction( activity to fragment) ?

Comment: Yes, 100%. I'm using it in Activities, Fragments, Services. Try it and you'll love it. Very easy to use, they have great docs and how-to guides to get you started.

Comment: haha no problem. If you need any more help , feel free to message me somehow, ping me in a comment here or whatever. Enjoy coding!

Comment: I don't see the need of adding a third party library when (at least for this question) the Android SDK can handle it

Comment: @Fighter42 libraries are there to make our life easier. You don't have to use anything, you can code your own `TextView` from scratch probably.

Answer (score 1):

If your button is interacting with your fragment, it should not be separated.

However, you can do:

```
getActivity().findViewById(...)
```

inside your fragment

Comment: butt this button have a listener in activity . there is no problem to define multiple listener for one element ?

Comment: Only the last one would apply